# Grammar Checkers: is there any *standard* API and protocol?

Tags: standards

I would like to know if there exist any **standard** API and protocol for grammar checking. I don't mean a library, I mean a standard API specification, to which various checkers from different vendors could conform.

### Update 2015-12-18

The closest I can find, is [Enchant](http://abisource.com/projects/enchant/). Unfortunately, it's for spell check only, not grammar check. The standard API in Windows, and MacOS, are also only for spell check, not grammar check.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is No, but just for clarity: In which context(s) - editors, compilers, others, all?

Comment: The context is an editor. I'm indeed afraid too, the answer is No, as this is not the first time I search for this and fail. While I'm also surprised there is no interoperable standard for this …